# Do something after check mark success icon shows?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

In dropzone, after an image is successfully loaded, there's a round icon with a check mark that shows to indicate things were successful. Is there an event that I can latch on to so I can do something after that icon appears and not before? I want to redirect users to another page upon successful upload but at the moment it's happening pretty much instantly as soon as I select my image using:

```
    init: function () {
        this.on("success", function(file, response) {
            window.location.href = 'google.com';
        });
    }
```

I just want to slow things down a bit, if you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to wait for a little bit to give the user a chance to see what's happening, use a timeout.

```
init: function () {
    this.on("success", function(file, response) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... I seemed to have answered my own question for anyone who may find this later.

I used this:

```
    init: function () {
        this.on("uploadprogress", function(file, progress) {
            if(progress == 100) {
                window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
            }
        });
    }
```